# How to connect IKEA Tradfri Gateway to a WiFI?

Tags: ikea-tradfri

The IKEA Tradfri gateway comes with an Ethernet cable but everyone online talks about it being connected to a WiFi. I find teardowns of the hardware that it has WiFi chips and there is a "connect" button on it.

But how to I actually connect to a WiFi? The connect button doesn't connect it with WPS (my first thought), the Tradfri app doesn't have any Wifi settings section - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it has a WiFi chip and it's not the Zigbee radio? I do not believe the bridge can join the Wifi

Comment: IIRC the connect button is for pairing Zigbee devices, not WPS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IKEA TRÅDFRI gateway doesn't offer Wi-Fi connectivity on its own. To access your TRÅDFRI gateway through Wi-Fi, you must first plug it into your Wifi network with the LAN cable provided.

This information is not (yet) provided in the printed TRÅDFRI gateway manual, but it shows up when performing initial setup through the TRÅDFRI app.

Comment: This answer isn’t clear to me. Is seems like it’s saying that after you plug in to LAN you are able to connect via WiFi only, but I can’t see how to do that. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: There is no Wi-Fi in the IKEA TRÅDFRI gateway. If you connect it with an Ethernet cable to your home network, the IKEA TRÅDFRI gateway will become visible in your home network.
But... this only works if you have a wireless network deployed in your home, and with the IKEA TRÅDFRI gateway connected in the same network as your wireless network.
So, if you own a wireless router, you can plug the IKEA TRÅDFRI gateway with a patch cable to one of your wireless router's LAN ports, and then it will be accessible through Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 3):

The Tradfri gateway is not a WPS certified or a wi-fi certified product, it's a wired product to your router.

The app is only usable when connected to your router's wifi. If you want to control devices outside of the wifi network, you must enaled Google Assistant or Amazon Alexa. Tradfri bulbs and remotes are also compatible Philips Hue or Smartthings, you can use the tradfri devices standalone on these 2 systems but without the gateway you won't receive firmware updates.